# replace an application using wix

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

I maintain two flavors of an application. Only one should be installed on each machine.

Let's say that I got application A installed on a machine. Now the user wants to install application B. The installer should replace A and install B.

Is it possible to tell the windows installer via WIX to silently replace another application?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this via the same mechanism that supports a major upgrade. Give each MSI a unique `UpgradeCode`. Then add an `Upgrade` element that detects the *other* MSIs `UpgradeCode`. Then add an `UpgradeVersion` element that will detect the *other* MSIs version correctly (could be the version number). You can use the `Property` attribute from the `UpgradeVersion` element to display special UI or otherwise condition stuff in your MSI to say, "Hey, I detected the other application".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the WiX bootstrapper functionality called Burn. You can create a bootstrapper (setup.exe) containing the logic for what packages need installed/removed.

Comment: I even got a Burn bootstrapper. But how do I teach it to uninstall a product?